# reducing repetitive code in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using this same block of code in numerous PHP files and sometimes in the same PHP file (e.g., when there's an `if/else`. I know there's a better way, but I'm not quite sure how to do it. I want to replace this big block with something, but not sure what fits. `require` maybe?

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$database = 'dev_testing';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'XXXXXX';
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: you only connect to the DB **ONCE**. There's no point in multiple connections, unless you need to access the db with different credentials. therefor you put that into a function or separate file, and include/require it once at the start of the script. people blindly spit on global variables, but a shared db handle is a perfect usage case for a global.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers by @maalls and @TahaPaksu are good, but @marcB's comment is even better: usually you'd want to connect to the database only once per script execution. I don't want to kick you right in the direction of [dependency injection](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html), but as an intermediate solution, I'd like to suggest this class, which looks roughly like a singleton, but is actually the [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) pattern implementation (see also [PHP Design Patterns](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) for other pattern examples).

Anyway: the code:

```
class Database() {

  static private $connection = null;

  public static function getConnection() {
    if (static::$connection === null) {
      $hostname = 'localhost';
      $database = 'dev_testing';
      $username = 'root';
      $password = 'XXXXXX';
      $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      static::$connection = $dbh;
    }

    return static::$connection;
  }
}
```

In your script you can call it using

```
$dbh = Database::getConnection();
```

You can call that line as often as you like but it will only connect to the database the first time it's called for that script. Subsequent calls will just return the same connection. This will save quite some overhead on your database.

Comment: You forgot to make the function `getConnection` static as well

Comment: Well my solution connects to the database only once.

Comment: require_once is only executed once...If you read the answer you will understand why this comment :)

Comment: @maalls Sorry, I interpreted your answer as `require`. Using `require_once` you actually risk breaking things. I added an explanation in a comment under your answer.

Comment: Thanks for this...if I'm making connections in functions or if/else statements, do I need to include `$dbh = Database::getConnection();` more than once or just one time at the top of my PHP file no matter what?

Comment: You probably want `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` as well to use the connection pool feature.

Comment: @jonmrich I think your code will look cleaner if you just read the code into a variable and use the variable from that point on instead of having a lot of calls to `Database::getConnection()`. But from a performance point of view there is hardly any difference, since getConnection will keep returning the same PDO instance. The only overhead is the function call itself, but that is neglectable. So use it whichever way you like best.

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate file (for ex. "connection.php"), put the code in it, and everywhere you need it, include the following at the begining of your code:

```
require_once('connection.php');
```

Comment: This will likely break the existing code without additional modifications. `require_once` is executed once. If you just put that snippet of code from the question in a file, and include it somewhere with `require_once`, it will set a variable `$dbh` in the calling scope. If you `require_once` it in the next place, the code will not be executed, and you won't get a new variable. `require` could be a drop-in replacement for OP, but `require_once` is likely going to break things, especially if OP uses their code inside functions or classes.

Comment: OP says he has this code in multiple files and sometimes more than once in the same file. If the code needs to be executed each time (and that is likely so, why else would it be there), then just putting require_once at the top won't work. This will only work if everything is one big, single global scope, but I sincerely hope that that is not your level of PHP scripting.

Comment: no, just putting require_once a the top will work as $dbh will be available everywhere as a global variable.
Based on the code provided by OP, I estimated it's overkill to introduce class concept or design pattern such as singleton into the solution.

KISS.

Comment: If you even have simple functions, you will need to import global variables in scope, so it doesn't work as-is and you'll have to make modifications. And even then, global variables, not using classes? That's keeping it *too* simple. If the scale of your application become bigger (more than a script kiddies home page), a single one-piece script isn't simple anymore, but has become an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: Golez I agree on what you say except one that the code should always be written to be scalable. I would have provided another answer if OP would have been familiar with include or saying he want to make a scalable app.

Answer (score 3):

you can use a global function which you include in top of your php files:

```
require_once("db.php");
```

file `db.php`:

```
function db_connect(){
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $database = 'dev_testing';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'XXXXXX';
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}
```

and in your files:

```
$dbh = db_connect();
... 
// don't forget to close db before you open a new connection!
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: Yea I forgot. sorry ;)